# auto calculate multiple dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to generate total from dropdown selected values using html and JavaScript, my code is working. but when i an changing my choices from dropdown i want the total to be changed on every dropdown selection. But its not happening.
like if i am entering value in after tax income and selecting fortnightly in dropdown, the total changes. but when am entering second and third value and setting them monthly and weekly respectively, it doesnt change according to selection.
where could be the problem?

```js
<script>
function asum() {
    var first = document.getElementById('a1').value;
    if (document.getElementById('a1').value == "") {
        var first = 0;
    }

    var second = document.getElementById('a2').value;
    if (document.getElementById('a2').value == "") {
        var second = 0;
    }

    var third = document.getElementById('a3').value;
    if (document.getElementById('a3').value == "") {
        var third = 0;
    }

    var forth = document.getElementById('fc4').value;
    if (document.getElementById('fc4').value == "") {
        var forth = 0;
    }

    var fifth = document.getElementById('fc5').value;
    if (document.getElementById('fc5').value == "") {
        var fifth = 0;
    }

    var aresult = parseInt(first) + parseInt(second) + parseInt(third);
    //aduration1
    if (document.getElementById('aduration3').value == "Monthly") {
        var aweekly = parseInt((aresult * 12) / 52);
        if (!isNaN(aresult)) {
            document.getElementById('a4').value = aweekly;

        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById('aduration3').value == "Fortnightly") {
        var weekly = parseInt((aresult * 26) / 52);
        if (!isNaN(aresult)) {
            document.getElementById('a4').value = weekly;

        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById('aduration3').value == "Weekly") {

        if (!isNaN(aresult)) {
            document.getElementById('a4').value = parseInt(aresult);

        }
    }
    //aduration2
    if (document.getElementById('aduration2').value == "Monthly") {
        var aweekly = parseInt((aresult * 12) / 52);
        if (!isNaN(aresult)) {
            document.getElementById('a4').value = aweekly;

        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById('aduration2').value == "Fortnightly") {
        var weekly = parseInt((aresult * 26) / 52);
        if (!isNaN(aresult)) {
            document.getElementById('a4').value = weekly;

        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById('aduration2').value == "Weekly") {

        if (!isNaN(aresult)) {
            document.getElementById('a4').value = parseInt(aresult);

        }
    }
    //aduration3
    if (document.getElementById('aduration3').value == "Monthly") {
        var aweekly = parseInt((aresult * 12) / 52);
        if (!isNaN(aresult)) {
            document.getElementById('a4').value = aweekly;

        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById('aduration3').value == "Fortnightly") {
        var weekly = parseInt((aresult * 26) / 52);
        if (!isNaN(aresult)) {
            document.getElementById('a4').value = weekly;

        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById('aduration3').value == "Weekly") {

        if (!isNaN(aresult)) {
            document.getElementById('a4').value = parseInt(aresult);

        }
    }
}

</script>
```

```html
   <div>
    <center>
        <table cellpadding="5px" style="border: 1px solid !important; padding: 10px !important;width: 40% !important;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%;">
                    <label>After tax salary</label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%;">
                    <input type="text" id="a1" placeholder="$" vlaue="0" onkeyup="asum();" />
                </td>
                <td style="width: 15%;">
                    <select id="aduration3" name="aduration3" onchange="asum();">
                        <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                        <option value="Fortnightly">Fortnightly</option>
                        <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 41%;">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Net passive income</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="a2" placeholder="$" onkeyup="asum();" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="aduration2" name="aduration2" onchange="asum();">
                        <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                        <option value="Fortnightly">Fortnightly</option>
                        <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Other income</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="a3" placeholder="$" onkeyup="asum();" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="aduration1" name="aduration1" onchange="asum();">
                        <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                        <option value="Fortnightly">Fortnightly</option>
                        <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" id="a4" placeholder="$" onclick="asum();" style="height: 30px !important; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px;" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label><b style="font-size:16px;" onclick="asum();"><u>TOTAL WEEKLY INCOME</u></b>
                        <label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="phone" id="a5" placeholder="$" onclick="bsum();" onkeyup="bsum();" style="height:30px !important;" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label><b style="font-size:16px;" onclick="bsum();"><u>TOTAL WEEKLY SURPLUS</u></b></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: JS is mandatory, or you can use jQuery?

Comment: no its not mandatory.. i can go with jquery also. just need what I want

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of your calculation with few simple lines of code in jQuery:

```
$(':input').on('change blur keyup', function(){
    var a = parseInt($('#a1').val()) || 0;
    var b = parseInt($('#a2').val()) || 0;
    var c = parseInt($('#a3').val()) || 0;
    var aresult = a + b + c;
    var ad2 = $('#aduration2').val();
    var ad3 = $('#aduration3').val();
    switch(ad2){
        case 'Monthly':
            $('#a4').val( (aresult * 12) / 52 );
            break;
        case 'Fortnightly':
            $('#a4').val( (aresult * 26) / 52 );
            break;
        case 'Weekly':
            $('#a4').val( aresult );
            break;
    }
    switch(ad3){
        case 'Monthly':
            $('#a5').val( (aresult * 12) / 52 );
            break;
        case 'Fortnightly':
            $('#a5').val( (aresult * 26) / 52 );
            break;
        case 'Weekly':
            $('#a5').val( aresult );
            break;
    }
});
```

Fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwov2ra6/1/)

PS in your code you mentioned `#aduration1` which is not present in you're HTML, and your making double calculation for `#aduration3`

Comment: hey yori, one more help please
I want that total to be generated automatically. not by a single click. how can I do that?
I m sory bt i m really new to jquery

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? With `change blur`, total is calculated whenever you change a select value, or you leave any input field.. No click event is needed

Comment: i m sorry if i m wrong somewhere.. all i wanted to say that.. when i m typing any value.. it will also display in the weekly total at the same time.. I meant to say current time calculation.
actually this is the code which I wanted. but its not working on localhost

Comment: Probably I got it. If you want your code to update anytime you press a key. just add `keyup` to events

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
$(':input').on('change blur', function(){
var a = parseInt($('#a1').val()) || 0;
var b = parseInt($('#a2').val()) || 0;
var c = parseInt($('#a3').val()) || 0;
var aresult = a + b + c;
var ad1 = $('#aduration1').val();
var ad2 = $('#aduration2').val();
var ad3 = $('#aduration3').val();
switch(ad1){
    case 'Monthly':
        $('#a4').val( (aresult * 12) / 52 );
        break;
    case 'Fortnightly':
        $('#a4').val( (aresult * 26) / 52 );
        break;
    case 'Weekly':
        $('#a4').val( aresult );
        break;
}
switch(ad2){
    case 'Monthly':
        $('#a4').val( (aresult * 12) / 52 );
        break;
    case 'Fortnightly':
        $('#a4').val( (aresult * 26) / 52 );
        break;
    case 'Weekly':
        $('#a4').val( aresult );
        break;
}
switch(ad3){
    case 'Monthly':
        $('#a4').val( (aresult * 12) / 52 );
        break;
    case 'Fortnightly':
        $('#a4').val( (aresult * 26) / 52 );
        break;
    case 'Weekly':
        $('#a4').val( aresult );
        break;
}
```

});